# Cannot print out 1 when doing Collatz contejure

Tags: java

I cannot print the 1 when wanting to program the Collatz contejure. Please help thanks.

Here is the problem: **Given natural number n. Generate a sequence of integers, described in the Collatz conjecture:**

Here is my code (Not snippet as it isn't clear (sample Input and Output at bottom):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        
        while (n > 1) {
            System.out.println(n);
            
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                n = n / 2;
            
            } else {
                n = (3 * n) + 1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

SAMPLE INPUT: 17

OUTPUT: 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2

**Need to print 1 as well**

Comment: While n > 0? Just print a 1? What debugging steps have you taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print 1 at the end of the loop.

```
while (n > 1) {
    System.out.println(n); 
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        n = n / 2;
        
    } else {
        n = (3 * n) + 1;
    }
}
System.out.println(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I changed the while loop to (n > 0) and I get "Time Limit Exceeded"

Comment: Sorry for late reply, was away. In regards to your answer, it did work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When demonstrating the `Collatz Conjecture`, you normally print after the computation, so move the print statement to the end of the loop. If you want to show what entered value was used to start the process, print it first, outside the loop.

```
System.out.println("Starting with " + n);
while (n > 1) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        n = n / 2;
        
    } else {
        n = (3 * n) + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(n); 
}
```